# How to change row names based off input from different dataframe

Tags: r, string, rename

Say I have df1 that contains names in column 1 and numerical values in the other columns, and I have df2 that contains the same set of names in column 2 and a unique corresponding identifier in column 1.

The order of the names in the dfs don't match so I need a way to replace df1 names with df2 identifiers.

I know I can do something similar with the dplyr rename function but my dataframes are HUGE so that's a lot to manually write out. I thought this could be done in base R with a simple for/if loop using logical arguments but I feel like there has to be an easier way? Any help, tips or tricks would be appreciated.

For example:

```
View(df1)
```

| Name | Value | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Heart | 2 | ... |
| Brain | 5 | ... |
| Blood | 10 | ... |
| Lung | 3 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

```
View(df2)
```

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| H | Heart |
| L | Lung |
| Br | Brain |
| Bl | Blood |
| ... | ... |

After code:

```
View(df1)
```

| Name | Value | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| H | 2 | ... |
| Br | 5 | ... |
| Bl | 10 | ... |
| L | 3 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: what if you just join the dataframes: `dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Name" = "Type"))`

Comment: Just a little FYI-- row names are a thing that are different from columns. The data you show just has columns, no row names.